# Apache and JBoss mod_cluster speed up reload

Tags: performance, apache-2.4, jboss, ajp, mod-cluster

As an alternative to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/671680/force-apache-to-reload-crl-without-reloading-everything), is it possible to decrease the amount of time that it takes for the Apache (httpd) server to pick up the JBoss servers after the Apache server reloads? As of right now, it is taking between 10 and 20 seconds; I would like it to take closer to one or two seconds.

EDIT: Here is the relevant section of the `standalone.ha` configuration file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.2">
    <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" proxy-list="redacted:8888,redacted:8888" connector="ajp">
        <dynamic-load-provider>
            <load-metric-type="busyness"/>
        </dynamic-load-provider>
    </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Try using proxyList instead of multicast for autodiscovery http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html/java.properties.html#mcmp

Comment: @FedericoSierra I have added the relevant section of the configuration. I am already using proxy-list.

Comment: Try to decrease the value of `socket-timeout` and `stop-context-timeout` in your settings. http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html/java.properties.html#mcmp

Comment: Another value that can be useful is `ping` in the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use PeristSlots on in the httpd mod_cluster configuration. It will persist the current state and use that as the starting configuration after a restart.